# Terminology for subsequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, terminology

Note: I'll index all my sequences by $\mathbb N$, so I drop the indices in the sequence notation.

The notion of a subsequence of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence obtained by deleting some terms in the sequence. For example, $\{ a_{2n} \}$ is the sequence obtained of all terms of $\{a_n\}$ with even index. Formally, a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of the form $a_{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi$ is an increasing function from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb N$.

With this notation, $\{ a_{[\sqrt{n}]} \}$ (where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$) is not a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ since it corresponds to $a_0,a_1,a_1,a_1,a_2,a_2,\dots$ ($\phi(n)=[\sqrt{n}]$) is only nondecreasing.

Does it exist a widely accepted term for such a "subsequence" in this case where $\phi$ is nondecreasing?

Comment: Sequences are special examples of 'nets'. And this structure you're considering happens to be an example of a 'subnet'. Subsequences are special examples of subnets.